# TypeError: No matching signature found while using fillna(method='ffill')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Problem

I wanted to replace `NaN` values in my dataframe with values using `fillna(method='ffill')` (*fill missing values in a DataFrame or Series with the previous non-null value*), however the code example below resulted in error.

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

```py
File "pandas/_libs/algos.pyx", line 604, in pandas._libs.algos.__pyx_fused_cpdef
TypeError: No matching signature found
```

### Debug

I initially though, that data in the df are wrong, because `No matching signature found` is signalling, that there are no `NaN` values, so I printed all values and count of their occurence and it seems like there should be some `NaN` values.

```py
print(df['a'].value_counts(dropna=False))

# Output
NaN       1417
1733.0       1
1150.0       1
1168.0       1
...
1671.0       1
1706.0       1
1132.0       1
```

I have also tried to determine, whether there are any `NaN` value using following code

```py
print(f"isnull?: {df['a'].isnull().values.any()}")

# Output
isnull?: True
```

**What might be wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

I still do not know why, but I have discovered that other occurences of the `fillna` method in my code are working with data of `float32` type. This dataset has type of `float16`. So I have tried chaning the type to `float32` and it **solved the issue**!

```py
df = df.astype({
     'a': 'float32'
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I had same issue with `float16` format. Changing to `float32` helps.